# Multiple HTTPS and HTTP WCF endpoints error

Tags: .net, wcf, web-config, wcf-binding

I'm trying to configure a WCF project to work with both HTTPS and HTTP.

I've managed to to get this to work on my server (both HTTPS and HTTP) - works flawlessly when I debug remotely (using Chrome's extension "Advanced Rest Client"), but I keep getting "**Error 500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException**" on my localhost environment.

I've attached my code, note that I only tried to change **"Behavior_Users"** (simply to figure it out) but I do need this HTTP + HTTPS functionality for all of my interfaces.

**This is my Web.config**:

```
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicWebBinding">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="secureWebBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpsHelpPageEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behavior_Users">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Bare"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

    <services>
      <service name="TakesApp.MainWCF.Users">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Behavior_Users" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicWebBinding" contract="TakesApp.MainWCF.IUsers">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Behavior_Users" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureWebBinding" contract="TakesApp.MainWCF.IUsers">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**This is my method:**

```
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(Method = "*", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message Register(Stream body);
```

Hope you guys can help me, I tried searching the right answer for 2 days, no luck.

**Thanks a lot!!!**

Update: still nothing. thinking about simply giving it a different config for debug and release. I tried every combination of configuration. It works both HTTPS and HTTP when hosted on the server but it fails over POST in my localhost env. WCF sucks.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to the relevant part only?

Comment: Done, hope I didn't delete any relevant parts. Thanks

Comment: I'm also facing a similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found that this is a known WCF bug, specifically in my kind of debug environments - using the IIS express.

I tried to workaround it using web.config transformation (adding specific HTTPS endpoints to web.release.config) but it also has a serious bug that prevents you from changing anything but the first setting.

WCF is way too complicated for a simple networking facade in 2015's standards.

Anyway, what I did was programmatically setting up an HTTPS endpoint in runtime depending on the environment (production or not).

I added a new server host factory to my global.asax:

```
public class ExtendedServiceHostFactory : WebServiceHostFactory
        {
            protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
            {
                //Add host
                WebServiceHost host = (WebServiceHost)base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });

                //Add HTTP endpoint
                ServiceEndpoint httpEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType.GetInterfaces()[0], new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None), string.Empty);
                httpEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

                //Add HTTPS endpoint
                if (ToolBox.IsProduction()) //My proprietary indication for environment type, replace with yours
                {
                    ServiceEndpoint httpsEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType.GetInterfaces()[0], new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport), string.Empty);
                    httpsEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
                }

                return host;
            }
        }
```

And then I registered a service with this extension (in Application_Start):

```
//Routing
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(
               new ServiceRoute(
                   "Users", new ExtendedServiceHostFactory(),
                   typeof(Users)));
```

And now this obviously works.